# pandoc citations in revealjs from markdown

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js, citations, biblatex, pandoc-citeproc

I use pandoc to generate Reveal.js slides from a Markdown file. All the citations are dumped in in the last slide, so I finish the `.md` file with the title `# References`, which is fitting. However, all references are in the same slide, and they would need approximately three slides to fit. Only the first 5 or 6 are visible. Any way to split the references in several slides would be great.

This is the `-v` information:

```
pandoc 1.19.2.4
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.5, texmath 0.9.4.4, skylighting 0.3.3.1
```

This is the command that I am running:

```
pandoc -t revealjs -s -o out.html in.md -V revealjs-url=../lib --bibliography *.bib
```

Is there any way to split the references in several slides?

Comment: I have added `#refs { font-size: 0.5em; column-count: 2; }` in the custom css and the "patch" is _acceptable_, but far from ideal.

Comment: That's actually a nice, if slightly hacky solution. Alternatively, you could write a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) to modify the document and limit number of references per slide. Side note: there has been quite a bit of progress in the last 3½ years since pandoc 1.19.2.4 came out. You might want to update (but note that you'd also have to update revealjs).

Comment: Another semi-hack, but when using [quarto](https://quarto.org/) (which calls pandoc), slide content on the references slide in revealjs is by default set to be [smaller and scrollable](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#content-overflow).  This doesn't implement the feature you're asking about, but it's another workaround worth knowing about.  See [this issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/271).